# Using OR in grep

Tags: grep

I have the following 2 commands working as expected.

```
grep -B3 'Max_value: 127' proc_*.*
grep -B3 'Max_value: 32767' proc_*.*
```

But can I write a single grep command? There can be upto 4 Max Values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grep -B3 'Max_value: \(127\|32767\)' proc_*.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Give grep a regular expression:

```
grep -B3 'Max_value: (?:127|32767)' proc_*.*
```

Comment: It did not return expected results. SiegeX command does work correctly.